# Linux server sudo command not found

Tags: ruby, linux, bash, server, sudo

I am having Linux server with

> `2.6.32-673.8.1.lve1.4.3.el6.x86_64 - GNU/Linux`

and trying to run following commands :

```
 sudo apt-get update
```

> -bash: sudo: command not found

I have also tried - `sudo su`

> -bash: sudo: command not found

And for `lsb_release -a`

> -bash: lsb_release: command not found

I am trying to install ruby. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: what flavor of LInux is installed?

Answer (score 3):

`sudo` is in its own package.  You probably don't have it installed, so you'll have to login as `root` and install it.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, just showing the kernel version doesn't help much, so see if this returns anything: `cat /etc/*-release`

If it does, you could be using something like CentOS or any other flavor of linux, so apt-get may not work anyway.

Hopefully, you are logging in with root if sudo isn't available. Running `whoami` should let you know your username if you are not sure.

If you are root, then try (for CentOS) `yum install sudo` to get sudo or just `yum install ruby` to install Ruby. If yum is not found, then try `apt-get`. If that still doesn't work, then you could be using a system with a different package manager (like `emerge` for Gentoo Linux).

**EDIT**: Does anything happen if you try `/sbin/sudo` (or `/usr/sbin/sudo`)?

Comment: when I run cat /etc/*-release it returns cat: /etc/*-release: No such file or directory. And I have not access for root user. For this /sbin/sudo command I am getting -bash: /sbin/sudo: No such file or directory.

Comment: -bash: yum: command not found getting this error for yum install sudo.

Comment: Very interesting. So you're not using CentOS/RedHat. What is returned when you run the following:
`dmesg | head -10`

Answer (score 0):

Often sudo is not installed by default on distributions like Debian. 
Tipe into the console:

```
su -
```

After that try to install sudo with this line:

```
apt-get install sudo -y
```

To use sudo properly you should give yourself Superuser permissions:

```
usermod -aG sudo USERNAME
```

After this step reboot your device and everything should work fine.